# Creating Lexical Analyzer for java

Tags: java, programming-languages, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to create a lexical analyzer for

cond_exp → condition | condition op cond_exp

condition → single_cond | (condition) | cond_exp

single_cond → variable | variable' | constant

op → and | or | implies

constant → true | false | !true | !false

variable → p|q|r

---

for the switch case in lex operation i'm getting a duplicate case label, I would appreciate your help, This is what I have so far :

and as for an example this is a sample string : ((p' and q) implies (r or r'))

```
public class Q4Lexical {

    //character classes
    private static final String Letter="0";
    private static final String opLetter="0";
    private static final String unknown="99";
    private static final String EOF="100";

    //Token classes
    public static final String INT_LIT="10";
    public static final String IDENT="11";

    public static final String pVarible="20";
    public static final String qVarible="21";
    public static final String rVarible="22";

    public static final String andOperation="23";
    public static final String orOperation="24";
    public static final String impliesOperation="25";
    public static final String tConstant="26";
    public static final String fConstant="27";
    public static final String tpConstant="28";
    public static final String fpConstant="29";


    public static final String LEFT_PAREN="30";
    public static final String RIGHT_PAREN="31";

     // Global Variables
    public static int current=0;
    static String StringClass;
    static String lexeme="";
    static String nextChar;
    static int lexLen=0;
    static int token;
    static String nextToken;


    static String expression="((p' and q) implies (r or r'))";

    public static boolean isVarible (String c){
        if((c.equalsIgnoreCase("p")) || (c.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) ||
           (c.equalsIgnoreCase("r")) || (c.equalsIgnoreCase("p'")) ||
           (c.equalsIgnoreCase("q'")) || (c.equalsIgnoreCase("r'")))
                  return true;

        else return false;

    }

    public static boolean isOperation(String c){
     if((c.equalsIgnoreCase("and")) || (c.equalsIgnoreCase("or")) ||
           (c.equalsIgnoreCase("implies")))
                  return true;

        else return false;

    }

    public static boolean isSpace(String c){

        if(c.equalsIgnoreCase(" "))
            return true;
        else return false;

    }

    public static void getString(){
        if(current< expression.length()){
            nextChar= expression.substring(current);
            current++;
           if(isVarible(nextChar))
               StringClass=Letter;
           else if(isOperation(nextChar))
               StringClass=opLetter;
           else 
               StringClass=unknown;
        }
            else
            StringClass = "#";
    }

    public static void getNonBlank(){
        while(isSpace(nextChar))
            getString();

    }

    public static String lookup(String c){
        switch(c){
            case "(":
                addString();
                nextToken= LEFT_PAREN;
                break;
            case ")":
                addString();
                nextToken= RIGHT_PAREN;
                break;
            case "and":
                addString();
                nextToken= andOperation;
                break;
            case "or":
                addString();
                nextToken=orOperation;
                break;
            case "implies":
                addString();
                nextToken=impliesOperation;
                break;
            default:
                addString();
                nextToken=unknown;
                break;
        }
        return nextToken;
    }


    public static void addString(){
        if (lexLen <= 98) 

            lexeme+=nextChar;
        else
            System.out.println("Error - Lexeme is too long");

    }

    public static String lex(){
        lexeme="";
        lexLen=0;
        getNonBlank();

        switch(StringClass){
            case Letter:

                addString();
                getString();
                while(StringClass.equals(Letter) || StringClass.equals(opLetter)){
                    addString();
                    getString();
                }
        switch (nextToken) {
            case "q":
                nextToken=qVarible;
                break;
            case "p":
                nextToken=pVarible;
                break;
            case "r":
                nextToken=rVarible;
                break;
        }
                break;

            case opLetter:
                addString();
                addString();
                while (StringClass.equals(opLetter)){
                    addString();
                    getString();
                }
                nextToken=INT_LIT;
                break;


            case unknown:
                lookup(nextChar);
                getString();
                break;

            case EOF:
                nextToken=EOF;
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("Next Token is : "+nextToken+" Next Lexeme is : "+lexeme);
        return nextToken;


    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            getString();
        do {
            lex();
        } while (current != expression.length());
    }
     }
```

Comment: If you're seeing an error message and asking us to help with it, then please post the complete un-edited error message, and indicate which line(s) of code causes it.

Comment: The error is with the lex function - in case opLetter , saying that it's duplicate case label.

Comment: You're paraphrasing the message. Please post the **actual** and complete message in the body of your question. You've not shown us which line of code is causing the error. Please help us.

Comment: This is the error message that I receive when I run the program/////// Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - duplicate case label
 at q4.lexical.Q4Lexical.lex(Q4Lexical.java:146)
 at q4.lexical.Q4Lexical.main(Q4Lexical.java:197)
Java Result: 1====================Line 146 stands for The lex operation.... Switch (StrinClass) line ....And line 197 stands for Lex() in the main class at the end of the program

Comment: You're trying to run uncompilable code -- please never do this. Instead compile it and fix the compilation error before running. What error message does your Java **COMPILER** tell you? And which line is 197 of the Q4Lexical.java class? Also, this information is key to your question, so please do edit your question and include this information with the question, not in comments. Doing this will help us all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letter and opLetter both equal the same thing, "0",

```
// character classes
private static final String Letter = "0";
private static final String opLetter = "0";
```

and your compiler is complaining since you're not allowed to have two case constants be the same.

```
  switch (StringClass) {
  case Letter:

     // ....

  // not allowed
  case opLetter:
```

Plus it just doesn't make sense. Which case should be activated if StringClass is "0"?

Solution: don't have them equal the same thing. Better still, consider using enums.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response..But when I run the program it returns everything to line 99 which is an IDENT element instead of recognizing the elements.

Comment: @LoD: This now has **nothing** to do with your original question. Please don't have your question change like this as this now makes my answer completely invalid, making my work futile. Since it's a new problem, please mark this question as solved and ask a new question on this site.

Comment: @LoD: I've rolled back your question to its original state. Again, please ask a new question on this site for any new problems.

Comment: sure will, Thanks , And I'm sorry for changing the question, I will ask a new one as soon as possible.